# mySQL workbench function won't run when I try to test if it works

Tags: sql, function, mysql-workbench

Hello I wrote a function that gets data from 3 tables and input the wanted data into my own created table. After it puts all the data in to the table based on different conditions outputs the wanted data in a string. The problem is the function won't run at all for some reason. I'm thinking it might be a syntax error.

```
CREATE FUNCTION getRevenue(year1 int, year2 int) returns varchar(50) 
BEGIN
    declare result varchar(50);
    declare messege varchar(50);
    declare count1 float;
    declare count2 float;
    declare num int;
    declare num2 int;
    declare diff1 int;
    declare diff2 int;
    

    declare search varchar(50);
    if (year1= '' || year1=null) || (year2='' || year2=null) then
        set result="Input year is invalid!";
        return result;
    else
    
        
        
        create table num1 as (SELECT dreamhome.Courses.cid,dreamhome.Courses.credits,
        dreamhome.Tuitions.year,dreamhome.Tuitions.fee_per_credit
        from ((dreamhome.Students_Courses
        inner join dreamhome.Courses on dreamhome.Students_Courses.cid=dreamhome.Courses.cid)
        INNER JOIN dreamhome.Tuitions on dreamhome.Students_Courses.year = dreamhome.Tuitions.year)); 
        set num=  (SELECT sum(credits) from num1 where year = year1);
        set num2 = (SELECT sum(credits) from num1 where year = year2);
        set count1 = (select num * fee_per_year from num1 where year = year1);
        set count2 = (select num2 * fee_per_year from num1 where year = year2);
        
        if(count1>count2) then
            set diff1 = count1-count2;
            set result= 'year ' + cast(year1 as char) + ' has revenue: ' + cast(diff1 as char) + ' more then ' + cast(year2 as char) + ' revunue: ' + cast(count2 as char);
            select result;
    if(count2>count1) then
    
    
                set diff1 = count2-count1;
            set result= 'year ' + cast(year2 as char) + ' has revenue: ' + cast(diff1 as char) + ' more then ' + cast(year1 as char) + ' revunue: ' + cast(count1 as char);
            select result;
    if(count2=count1)then
        set result = 'Year ' + cast(year1 as char) + ' and ' +cast(year2 as char) + ' have the same revenue: ' +cast(count1 as char);
        select result;
    return result;
    END ;
    delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use `()` with if, as there is a difference between the [if() function](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/if-function/) versus [if statements](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/if/). If blocks also need a closing `end if;` Using an `if .. elseif .. else` block, only 1 `end if;` needed at the end.
2. The create table select doesn't need the extra `()`, the one before the select and at the end should be enough.
3. No need to `select result` if the result is set (like it is in the first if), so these have been removed.

   ```
   if year1= '' || year1=null || year2='' || year2=null  then
       set result="Input year is invalid!";
       return result;
   else

       create table num1 as (SELECT dreamhome.Courses.cid,dreamhome.Courses.credits,
       dreamhome.Tuitions.year,dreamhome.Tuitions.fee_per_credit
       from dreamhome.Students_Courses
       inner join dreamhome.Courses on dreamhome.Students_Courses.cid=dreamhome.Courses.cid
       INNER JOIN dreamhome.Tuitions on dreamhome.Students_Courses.year = dreamhome.Tuitions.year); 
       set num=  (SELECT sum(credits) from num1 where year = year1);
       set num2 = (SELECT sum(credits) from num1 where year = year2);
       set count1 = (select num * fee_per_year from num1 where year = year1);
       set count2 = (select num2 * fee_per_year from num1 where year = year2);

       if count1 > count2 then
           set diff1 = count1-count2;
           set result= 'year ' + cast(year1 as char) + ' has revenue: ' + cast(diff1 as char) + ' more then ' + cast(year2 as char) + ' revunue: ' + cast(count2 as char);
       elseif count2 > count1 then
           set diff1 = count2-count1;
           set result= 'year ' + cast(year2 as char) + ' has revenue: ' + cast(diff1 as char) + ' more then ' + cast(year1 as char) + ' revunue: ' + cast(count1 as char);
       else -- counts are the same
           set result = 'Year ' + cast(year1 as char) + ' and ' +cast(year2 as char) + ' have the same revenue: ' +cast(count1 as char);
       end if; 
       return result;
   end if; -- end the first if/else block.
   ```